# Parse Table presented in WebControl

Tags: c#, linq, html-parsing, dom

**The HTML is being displayed in a WinForm that is using the built-in WebControl**

I've decided to try HTMLAgilityPack.

```
var query = from table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='TABLEBORDER').Cast<HtmlNode>() 
            from row in table.SelectNodes("tr").Cast<HtmlNode>() 
            from cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td").Cast<HtmlNode>() 
            select new {Table = table.Id, CellText = cell.InnerText}; 

foreach(var cell in query) { 
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", cell.Table, cell.CellText); 
}
```

I updated the code as per @L.B
I get the following output

```
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1e94) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
: 
Target

: 
Triggerenabled?

: 
Account

: 
Passwordchanged?


: 
Error message(if any)

The thread '<No Name>' (0x2564) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The other data is clearly visible on the webcontrol.

Comment: If you want to parse nontrivial HTML without using any 3rd party code, you're in for a rough ride. You could probably do this with some complex regular expressions, or some ugly substring search/extract code. But it would be brittle and hard to maintain. The other alternative is writing your own more general purpose HTML parser, which will take years off your life. Parsing HTML is tough to get right, I'd use something that's been done already unless you have a very compelling reason not to.

Comment: No 3rd party plug-ins strikes me as an unreasonable requirement in this day and age.  What's the reason for this?  HTML5 data attributes with a sprinkle of jQuery easily solves this problem.

Comment: I think it was only ever a reasonable requirement before the internet existed ;) why reinvent what you can recycle?

Comment: I tried WATIN in the past and I found that IE needed Admin privs to parse html. So I gave up on WATIN. I need something that non-admins can use to perform data entry (I did all the Data entry with webControl1.Document.GetElement...

Comment: .. what exactly are you trying to do? It sounds like, maybe, automate filling out a form (on someone else's web site) and/or scrape from a winforms app using the browser control?

Comment: I am filling out a form. But the form is hosted on our internal network and is generated by an application.

Comment: Can you just skip the browser altogether and generate the correct POST? Generally, just use the application's API instead of trying to automate a browser.

Comment: I wish I can. But it's not possible. The company paid big money for this crappy application.

Comment: @CocoaDev See how people can use my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077964/htmlagilitypack-is-parsing-my-table-incorrectly

Comment: Thanks for the info but seems like you removed your question/asnwer

Comment: @CocoaDev, Yes user [SoftwareIsFun](http://stackoverflow.com/users/399508/software-is-fun) deleted his question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The page has other tables but I am only interested in the one with the class being "TABLEBORDER".

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='TABLEBORDER']");
```

**EDIT**

```
var res = table.Descendants("tr")
               .Select(tr => tr.Descendants("td")
                               .Select(td => td.InnerText)
                               .ToList())
               .ToList();
```

**EDIT2**

```
foreach (List<string> tr in res)
{
    foreach (string td in tr)
    {
        Console.Write("[{0}] ", td);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and I get the TH output. I don't see the td values.

Comment: Thanks. I am very new to LINQ. Is the data being stored in res?

Comment: @CocoaDev Yes and it is `List<List<string>>`

Comment: I added 2 lines of code and I am getting confused about Lists.